# Find an explicit formula to calculate the number of a such that $a\bot \frac{n}{GCD(a,n)}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Original question:

> Find an explicit formula to calculate the number of a such that $a^{\phi(n)+1}\mod n=a$

I managed to prove that $a^{\phi(n)+1}\mod n=a$ is equivalent to $a\bot \frac{n}{GCD(a,n)}$. After that I could not see any continuation. Can anyone please give any clues on how may I continue this or give a completely method that's easier? Thanks in advanced.

Proof of their equivalence:

If a is not coprime to $\frac{n}{GCD(a,n)}$, $a^b\mod n\land b>1$ can never be equal to a as there is at least one prime multiple of the result where the exponent is higher than the prime multiple's exponent in a.

Letting $GCD(a,n)=c$

If $a\bot \frac{n}{c}\land 0<a<b$, then $a\mod n=c\cdot\frac{a}{c}\mod\left( c\cdot\frac{b}{c}\right)=\frac{ab}{ac}ac=\frac{b}{c}ac=\frac{b}{c}cc^{-1}ac=a(b\mod c)$
$a^{\phi(b)+1}\mod b=c\cdot\frac{a}{c}\mod\left(c\cdot\frac{b}{c}\right)=c\left(\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^{\phi(b)+1}\mod\frac{b}{c}\right)=c\cdot\frac{a}{c}=a$

Comment: Let $n=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_t^{r_t}$. What can you say about the factorization of $a$, if $a$ is prime to $n/\gcd(a,n)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, I've tried that but I kinda gave up after having a quadruple summation that doesn't work

Comment: Quadruple summation? It seems to me that for each prime dividing $n$ there are exactly two choices for the power of that prime dividing $a$, which makes life pretty easy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh yeah, true. But how about a that has other prime factors that aren't n's factor

Comment: Good point. I think your function may equal the one tabulated at http://oeis.org/A055653 – and the formula given there is  $\prod(1+p_i^{e_i}-p_i^{e_i-1})$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, that answers the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this function is the same as the one tabulated at [oeis.org/A055653](http://oeis.org/A055653), for which the formula $$\prod(1+p_i^{e_i}-p_i^{e_i-1})$$ is given (where the $p_i$ are the distinct primes in the factorization $n=\prod p_i^{e_i}$).